# How do I pass the data totalAmount from the child to parent to another child component again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this `totalAmount` data from the cart.js and how can I pass it to the parent component(app.js) where I will be able to pass it to another child component(info.js). I tried passing it from the `Cart.js` to the parent, it won't work, this is what it would display:

> Identifier 'totalAmount' has already been declared

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-sampled-2-with-material-ui-table-pagination-with-reduced-cart-items-firebase-5id6gs?file=/src/Cart.js**strong text**

**In the cart.js**

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems, handleCartClearance, handleRemove, handleAdd }) => {

  const totalAmount = cartItems.reduce(
    (price, item) => price + item.quantity * item.price,
    0
  );

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

**In the App.js**
How can I pass the `totalAmount` to the `customerInfo` component?

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomerInfo cartItems={cartItems} /> 
      <br />
          <Cart
            cartItems={cartItems}
            handleCartClearance={handleCartClearance}
            handleRemove={handleRemove}
            handleAdd={handleAdd}
          />
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CustomerInfo component:**

```
const CustomerInfo = ({ cartItems }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstName, number, "info");
    console.log(cartItems, "cartItems, info");
    //console the totalAmount here
  };

  return (
    <Container style={{ padding: "12px" }}>

    </Container>
  );
};

export default CustomerInfo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since totalAmount calcul is only based on cartItems, which is a prop of Cart. I do believe this is not the responsibility of Cart to calcul it but the responsibility of its parent.

Comment: so I can just move the codes for totalAmount in the parent component and then from there I could pass it to both of the child components, right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely